# I am trying to send email in Laravel 5.2. It giving me erros as "InvalidArgumentException in Mailer.php line 410: Callback is not valid."

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I have provided host ,username ,password,port no. in .env and config/mail.php. I am sending email from localhost.

```
   public function sendEmail(){
          $data = array('name'=>"Swati Jadhav");
           $arrCategory=Category::getCategory();
          Mail::send('frontend.welcome',['arrCategory'=>$arrCategory] ,$data, function($message) {
                 $message->from('sender@gmail.com', 'text');
              $message->to('receiver@gmail.com', 'text')->subject('Welcome!');

          });

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mail::send` needs the callback as the 3rd parameter (not 4th). If you need to combine two parameter arrays you can do:

```
 Mail::send('frontend.welcome',array_merge(['arrCategory'=>$arrCategory] ,$data), function($message) {
             $message->from('sender@gmail.com', 'text');
          $message->to('receiver@gmail.com', 'text')->subject('Welcome!');

  });
```

Comment: Thank You @apokryfos. I have done suggested changes in my code. Now It is giving me error like this "Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383: Expected response code 220 but got code "502", with message "502 Command not implemented
"

Comment: @Swati could be related to https://laravel.io/forum/04-27-2014-sending-mailexception

Comment: @ apokryfos I have already tried that. It giving still same error